# Passing base64-encoded data in php

Tags: php, base64, xss

I have a page that receive via GET a base64 encoded data, it print data in an input hidden and it pass via get to another page.

The problem is this: when i pass

```
"Peuq/0X4XhFV+XNa8T06qFrP8lRadORUQBGJ1w6D4m33Jaqx/skKDEJIxjldBrcklboL/uB4C65cjz3BHMPmd3moEJ4GTK5k5Jwf9Ny4BA467bwgeaHJuOS+CjwFlIOzrhSWHTMVl4zWVvwMauuFAjhuMjOOj0/X5L12IcwGTTqLgHo"
```

via GET it becomes

```
"Peuq/0X4XhFV XNa8T06qFrP8lRadORUQBGJ1w6D4m33Jaqx/skKDEJIxjldBrcklboL/uB4C65cjz3BHMPmd3moEJ4GTK5k5Jwf9Ny4BA467bwgeaHJuOS CjwFlIOzrhSWHTMVl4zWVvwMauuFAjhuMjOOj0/X5L12IcwGTTqLgHo"
```

...so openssl can't work. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why and how will data be "damaged" when using `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but openssl successfully decript a base64-encoded, but if I use htmlspecialchars on it, openssl doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Then show us the difference between the not-special-char'd string and the special-char'd string and how you're using them exactly.

Comment: @deceze you were right.. the problem wasn't special chars.. can you help me?

Comment: Or, with little less security, try base 62 or even base 32 encoding. Unfortunately no built in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain characters in the URL are special, like `+` which stands for a space. To send arbitrary data via the URL, you need to *URL escape* it to avoid characters contained in the data being recognized as "special characters". Since you're putting the data into HTML, you *also* need to HTML-escape it to avoid characters in the URL-encoded data being recognized as special HTML characters. Hence:

```
$data = /* some data */;
$base64Data = base64_encode($data);
$urlData = urlencode($base64Data);
$htmlData = htmlspecialchars($urlData);
printf('<input type="hidden" value="%s" name="pass-it-on">', $htmlData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Base64 can output `+` signs which are interpreted as spaces when sent in the URL. You can use [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) to mitigate this:

```
<?php
$base64_data = $_GET['base64'];
$url_data = urlencode($base64_data);
$field_data = htmlspecialchars($url_data);
printf('<input type="hidden" value="%s" name="pass-it-on">', $field_data);
?>
```

On page two:

```
<?php
$base64_data = $_GET['pass-it-on'];
$real_data = base64_decode($base64_data);
?>
```

Note that there's no need to decode the `htmlspecialchars` ur `urlencode` calls since this is done automatically.

Comment: I realized the problem isn't special chars...can you help me? (added details)

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the new question.