# base64 image conversion with str_replace of URL

Tags: php, image, base64

I'm running into a problem with some PHP code where I think I know the problem, but it still seems quirky to me.  Basically, my end goal is to write a number of images out to base64.

Here is the link to the [full file](https://bitbucket.org/sageth/phparcade/src/c61dd6a78723d952b5245a54e1c4c7815efa83d5/plugins/site/functions.php?at=master) in question.  The very bottom function (base64_encode_image) is the new one I wrote.  obcallbackreplace() has the code that does the find and replace of the strings [themedir], etc.  It's almost like it just doesn't know what to do and gives no response.  I feel like I have a logic error somewhere, but just can't see it.

Function to convert to base64 image:

```
function base64_encode_image($imageurl, $filetype, $curlopt=array()) {
isset($response) ? $response = '' : $response = '';
$ch = curl_init();
$default_curlopt = array(
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 2,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 AlexaToolbar/alxf-1.54 Firefox/3.6.13 GTB7.1"
);
$curlopt = array(CURLOPT_URL => $imageurl) + $curlopt + $default_curlopt;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlopt);
$image = curl_exec($ch);
if($response === false){
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

$base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image);
return $base64;
}
```

Abbreviated function that does the string find and replace with URL:

```
function obcallbackreplace($buffer) {
global $cfg;
$themename = get_site_config("name=theme");
$themedir = $cfg["baseurl"]."plugins/site/themes/".$themename."/";
$buffer = str_replace('[themedir]', $themedir, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

I should be able to just do like this and it should work... but it doesn't.

```
<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('[themedir]images/logo.png','png')" />
```

---

**Test 1:**

```
<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('[themedir]images/logo.png','png');?>" />
```

Output is (Note the missing $image parameter):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64," />
```

---

**Test 2:** (note: This is a non-public server)

```
<img src="<?php echo base64_encode_image('http://sageth-dev/plugins/site/themes/premium/images/logo.png','png');?>" />
```

Output is: ...(super long base64 string that does exactly what I want it to do.)

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAZA />
```

---

**Test 3:**
If I change the base64 function to:

```
return 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image);
```

Output is (note that $image isn't passed):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,"/>
```

---

**Test 4:**
Last, if I use this as the function (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208214/passing-base64-encoded-data-in-php)):

```
$base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image);
$base64 = urlencode($base64);
$base64 = htmlspecialchars($base64);
return $base64;
```

I get:

```
<img src="data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2C" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that obcallbackreplace() runs after base64_encode_image() does, so you're not processing the parameter $imageurl. The line "$curlopt = array(CURLOPT_URL => $imageurl)..." runs with the url "[themedir]images/logo.png" from your Test 1 above, which is not valid url.

You need to parse "[themedir]" before adding the $imageurl variable to the Curl options. Something like this should work:

```
$default_curlopt = array(...);
global $cfg;
$themename = get_site_config("name=theme");
$themedir = $cfg["baseurl"]."plugins/site/themes/".$themename."/";
$imageurl = str_replace('[themedir]', $themedir, $imageurl);
$curlopt = array(CURLOPT_URL => $imageurl) + $curlopt + $default_curlopt;
```

Comment: This makes sense. If I added URL encoding, I could see [themedir] was being picked up instead of the URL, but - for some reason - I completely missed that obcallbackreplace was called after the base64 function.  Thanks!