# How do I declare a base64 of a json inside an api request?

Tags: php, json, rest

I am trying to use a base64 encoding of a json array inside an api request. 
This is the json array:

```
{"action":"START_STREAMING","metricsList": [{"category":"HARDWARE","subcategory":"MACHINE","component":"DASHBOARD","metric":"STATUS"},":[{"category":"HARDWARE","subcategory":"MACHINE","component":"DASHBOARD","metric":"TIME"},{"category":"HARDWARE","subcategory":"MACHINE","component":"DASHBOARD","metric":"INFO"}],"duration":60}
```

This is my current solution:

```
  $command = base64_encode({"action":"START_STREAMING","metricsList": [{"category":"HARDWARE","subcategory":"MACHINE","component":"DASHBOARD","metric":"STATUS"},":[{"category":"HARDWARE","subcategory":"MACHINE","component":"DASHBOARD","metric":"TIME"},{"category":"HARDWARE","subcategory":"MACHINE","component":"DASHBOARD","metric":"INFO"}],"duration":60});

  $request = [
        'command' => $command
    ];
```

I am pretty sure this isnt quite right. Any help?

Comment: are you using this conversion  from ajax or direct php

Comment: direc php @prasanth

Answer (score 0):

> Even though Base64 encoding is not an encryption, sometimes it can be
>   useful to pass data or parameters in a single string.

**Base64 Encode for URL:**

```
function b64link_encode($string){
    $string = base64_encode($string);
    $string = urlencode($string);
    return $string ;
}
```

encode that data and pass

**Base64 Decode for URL:**

```
function b64link_decode($string){
    $string = urldecode($string);
    $string = base64_decode($string);
    return $string ;
}
```

> or you can do
>   [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208214/passing-base64-encoded-data-in-php)

Certain characters in the URL are special, like + which stands for a space. To send arbitrary data via the URL, you need to URL escape it to avoid characters contained in the data being recognized as "special characters". Since you're putting the data into HTML, you also need to HTML-escape it to avoid characters in the URL-encoded data being recognized as special HTML characters. Hence:

```
$data = /* some data */;
$base64Data = base64_encode($data);
$urlData = urlencode($base64Data);
$htmlData = htmlspecialchars($urlData);
printf('<input type="hidden" value="%s" name="pass-it-on">', $htmlData);
```